# Push div to the right on opening menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a slide (from left to right) menu, and it seems to be working. 
Is there a way I can push the "showmenu" div to the right after opening the menu?
Right now it is staying on it's place and I have no clue how to take care of this issue.

CSS:

```
.buttonMenu {
font-family:Arial;
font-weight:bold;
width:100%;
padding:10px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
border:0px;
color:white;
}
.buttonMenu:hover {
font-family:Arial;
font-weight:bold;
width:100%;
padding:10px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
border:0px;
color:white;
}
.buttonMenu:focus {
outline:0;
}
#showmenu {
border-top-right-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:5px;
padding-top:25px;
padding-bottom:25px;
background-color:black;
font-family:Arial;
color:white;
position:fixed;
top:45%;
left:0;
border-width:3px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black;
border-left-width:0;
}
#showmenu:hover {
color:black;
background-color:white;
}
#menu {
display:none;
border:0;
border-right-width:2px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
top:0;
left:0;
height:100%;
width:300px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position:fixed;
}
#accountDetails {
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial;
color:white;
padding:15px;
height:100px;
width:270px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#profilePic {
vertical-align:middle;
border-radius:15px;
border-width:4px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:rgba(124, 252, 0, 1);
}
.black {
background-color:black;
color:black;
height:2px;
border:0;
}`
```

HTML:
    `<div id="menu">
    <div id="accountDetails">
    <img id="profilePic" width="100px" height="100px" src="">Account name</div>
    <hr class="black">
    <button class="buttonMenu">HOME</button>
    <button class="buttonMenu">GAMES</button>
    <button class="buttonMenu">COMMUNITIES</button>
    <button class="buttonMenu">PLAYERS</button>
    </div>
    <div id="showmenu">M
    <br>E
    <br>N
    <br>U</div>`

JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showmenu').click(function () {
        $('#menu').toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sgf5f3w0/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sgf5f3w0/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jquery.transfrom2d.js](http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.transform.js/) plugin to animate the CSS property of `#showmenu`.

Download the plugin from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js/master/jquery.transform2d.js) and add it to your HTML.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgf5f3w0/7/)[Edited]

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cnt = 0;
    $('#showmenu').click(function () {
        if (cnt % 2 == 0) {
            $('#menu').animate({'left': '-2px'});
            $('#showmenu').animate({'left': '300px'});
        } else {
            $('#menu').animate({'left': '-302px'});
            $('#showmenu').animate({'left': '0px'});
        }
        cnt++;
    });
});
```

#### CSS:

```
#menu {
    display: block;
    border:0;
    border-right-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    top:0;
    left:-302px;
    height:100%;
    width:300px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position:fixed;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cnt = 0;
    $('#showmenu').click(function () {
        if (cnt % 2 == 0) {
            $('#menu').animate({'left': '-2px'});
            $('#showmenu').animate({'left': '300px'});
        } else {
            $('#menu').animate({'left': '-302px'});
            $('#showmenu').animate({'left': '0px'});
        }
        cnt++;
    });
});
```

```css
.buttonMenu {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border:0px;
    color:white;
}
.buttonMenu:hover {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border:0px;
    color:white;
}
.buttonMenu:focus {
    outline:0;
}
#showmenu {
    border-top-right-radius:15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:5px;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    background-color:black;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
    top:45%;
    left:0;
    border-width:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    border-left-width:0;
}
#showmenu:hover {
    color:black;
    background-color:white;
}
#menu {
    display: block;
    border:0;
    border-right-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    top:0;
    left:-302px;
    height:100%;
    width:300px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position:fixed;
}
#accountDetails {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:white;
    padding:15px;
    height:100px;
    width:270px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#profilePic {
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-radius:15px;
    border-width:4px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:rgba(124, 252, 0, 1);
}
.black {
    background-color:black;
    color:black;
    height:2px;
    border:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <div id="accountDetails">
        <img id="profilePic" width="100px" height="100px" src="">Account name</div>
    <hr class="black">
    <button class="buttonMenu">HOME</button>
    <button class="buttonMenu">GAMES</button>
    <button class="buttonMenu">COMMUNITIES</button>
    <button class="buttonMenu">PLAYERS</button>
</div>
<div id="showmenu">M
    <br>E
    <br>N
    <br>U</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js/master/jquery.transform2d.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! :) 
I'm wondering, is it also possible to make the menu div slide from left to right, instead of from top-left to bottom-right? Like a real sliding menu

Comment: Awesome, amazing, super! Thanks! :)
I even see what I did wrong, I guess I shouldn't have used the display:none;, but just push the menu to the left off-screen like you did. Didn't think of it, but it makes sense - again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would not install a third party plugin just for this. I would simply add/remove a left negative margin. It is very simple. You can add transitions to CSS without the need for extra third party plugins.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/sgf5f3w0/9/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#showmenu').click(function () {
            $('#menu').toggleClass("showMenuNav");
        });
    });
```